# AWS Opensearch two service domains for multiregion read / write application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I want to use AWS OpenSearch for multi-region read / write application to achieve low latency/performance. In Opensearch I have found that we can create two service domains.
So please let me know, Whether AWS OpenSearch supports multi-region writes in both service domain & replicate that data or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support multi-regional writes. It [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/replication.html) cross regional replication in master slave mode.

To solve the problem with high latency we need to identify the cause of this latency first.
You can place OpenSearch consumer service in the same region as OpenSearch to have minimal network latency. End users will work with consumer, not with OpenSearch.

You can use caches and CDN between end users and consumer to minimize network latency if that is a problem.
In the end the maximum network latency in AWS network is about 100 ms (between Australia and US), that is not very big for many cases.

In some extreme cases you do need to place OpenSearch closer to your users but chance you need that are near 0.